# xspf player - name of object or code that defines current song highlighting?

Tags: flash, xspf

I'm creating a new look for the xspf player:
http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/

The playlist highlights the current song being played. I'd like to change the color but can't find where that option is listed in the .flv file, or in the actionscript file.

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [xspf.fla](http://musicplayer.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/musicplayer/cvs-repository/development/xspf_player.fla?revision=1.9) file, it appears that the highlight is a white rectangle on Layer 1 of frame 2 of the **mc.track_bg** symbol - you could try changing the colour of this rectangle manually if you wanted to.

Comment: I thought I had looked everywhere... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who cannot update the Flash source you can use *playlist selectedColor* in the skin.xml.

See Skin Documentation at http://www.lacymorrow.com/projects/jukebox/skindoc.html.